# Laravel 5.2: Route without running Laravel Serve not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a Laravel 5.2 Practice application which is running with Laravel Serve running like this 
[image: Laravel 5.2 Practice]

Working Perfectly , The form blade is following

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('form')
<div class="col-md-4">
@if(count($errors)>0)
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
        {{ $error }}
    @endforeach
</div>
@endif
<form action="/" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>I want to</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="action">
            <option value="greet">Greet</option>
            <option value="hug">Hug</option>
            <option value="kiss">Kiss</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>this person</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" >
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success "> Do it! </button>
    </div>
  </form>
 </div>
 @endsection
```

With Following POST route entry in routes

```
Route::post('/', 'adminController@post');
```

**Problem**

When I run the same application using Wamp server instead of Laravel Server

[image: Laravel 5.2 Practice Application]

I press submit button, it takes me to localhost

[image: Wamp Server Localhost]

Is it possible to write a route entry which can perform in both situations, with and without Laravel Server running. ?

These are my routes

```
Route::get('/', [
  'uses' => 'adminController@index',
  'as'  => 'home'
]);
Route::get('/hug/{name?}', [
  'uses' => 'adminController@hug',
  'as'  => 'hug'
]);
Route::get('/kiss/{name?}', [
  'uses' => 'adminController@kiss',
  'as'  => 'kiss'
]);
Route::get('/form', [
  'uses' => 'adminController@form',
  'as'  => 'form'
]);

Route::post('/', 'adminController@post')->name('index'); 


Route::auth();

Route::get('/home', 'adminController@index');
Route::get('/logout',function(){
Auth::logout();
 return Redirect::to('/home');
});
```

Comment: Route::post('/', 'adminController@post')->name('index'); and add in form action route('index')

Comment: what should I write in action of the form?

Comment: add {{ route('index') }} to form action

Comment: @sunilwananje now it takes me to http://localhost/blog_new/public/ means again on root. I have edited the post, see my routes file

Comment: on which page you want to redirect?

Comment: I want the controller function to be executed which is adminController@post

Comment: in route '/' means  localhost/blog_new/public now it goes  to adminController@post  add  dd("adminController@post ") to your post function to check it working or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you hard-coded the / in

```
<form action="/" method="post">
```

I highly recommend using [Laravel Collective](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html) for your forms

You can open a form giving a route, not an absolute URL like this.
Read the documentation.

```
echo Form::open(['route' => 'route.name'])
```

Laravel Collective will solve all your issues like this. It has model binding and CSRF protection. Easy to use.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the form collections, in the form action, replace the `action="/"` to your route url:

```
<form action="your_post_url" method="post">
    <!-- protect your application from cross-site request forgery (CSRF) attacks. -->
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <!-- your form here -->
</form
```

To find the route url, you can use the command `php artisan route:list`in your console

Answer (score 0):

Alright I have fixed it by doing following.

**Route Entry**

```
Route::post('/post', 'adminController@post')->name('post');
```

**Form Open**

```
<form action="{{ route('post') }}" method="post">
```

Previously the Route was pointing to /. I still have no idea why mentioning /post fixed it when I named the route to post, but its working now

Comment: Now it works on both, with Laravel Server running url and without